# Need help editing Wordpress CSS code - my sub menu disappears on hover

Tags: css, wordpress

Hope you can help - im extremely new and not clued up on code/editing css so hoping someone can spell it out for me. I have the problem whereby I can't keep my sub menu visible. When I hover over the parent item 'Destinations' it appears, and then when I move down to select one of the sub menu items it disappears.

can someone please check for me?

www.thespindrifters.com -  It is under the Destinations tab

thanks in advance

Comment: I can't find that submenu, checked your source code, but no `<ul>` in `<li>` ?

Comment: I was playing with it and now the sub menu shows but is constantly showing rather than when you just hover on it. If you could check now id be very very grateful! Thanks

Comment: what you  exactly  want to do with your menu Destination and its sub menu Malaysia

Answer (score 0):

add/edit this CSS in your code:

remove padding from `.site-bar` it currently is `13px 0`, set it to 0;

add padding to `.site-tools` as `padding: 13px 0;` - will fix social icons in navbar

add this:

```
.navigation > li > a { padding: 13px 0 }
.navigation > li > ul { display: none; }
.navigation > li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

reason to remove padding from .site-bar and adding it to child elements is to prevent disappearing of menu when moving from parent link to submenu

Comment: you can play around with `top` attribute of submenu, remove `padding-top` from main menu etc..and if you're happy with my answer, please accept it ;)